# Input validation with Javascript in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

What I'm looking for is a way to control input validation (HTML5) inside my Javascript functions, for now I have this:

```
function validate_select(combo){
    var index = combo.selectedIndex;

    if(index == 0){
        combo.setCustomValidity('Choose an element.');
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

if(validate_select(combo_product)){
    //do something and then reset combo
    combo_product.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Which work fine and just like I want, but I have some other elements (no form) and I want to trigger the validation just like the combo but instead of using some customValidity I want to use the HTML5 default validation. Any help is appreciate.

Is it possible or I'm just getting it to complex? (maybe a simpler alternative?)

I would like to get a non-jQuery solution, if possible.

Comment: When you say "HTML5 validation", you actually mean input validation but in HTML5, correct? (As opposed to validating your code for compliance with HTML5). You may want to revise the title/tags.

Comment: @Michael Ok, I've edited the tags I'm kind of new with this. Thank you, for edition :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="#">
  <select required="required">
     <option value="" selected> Please Select </option>
     <option value="1"> option 1 </option>
     <option value="2"> option 2 </option>
     <option value="3"> option 3 </option>
</select>
 <input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/036easd8/

Comment: Sorry, in my case I can't use a form and I want to trigger the input validation in my Javscript functions...